# Tkinter imaging code will work inside of function but not outside, even with similar code

Tags: python, tkinter, winapi

so I've been trying to add a function which will display an image to inform the user if the caps lock button is engaged, much like what is used for a windows login and such.

I was able to get some working code which was as follows, all the necessary libraries were imported previously:

```
def capson(event=None):
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    file_name = os.path.join(dir_path, "images\\capslock.png")
    img=Image.open(file_name)
    img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    capslock_image=tkinter.Label(LoginPage, image=img)
    capslock_image.image=img
    capslock_image.place(x=375, y=251)

def capsoff(event=None):
    capslock_image.place_forget()

LoginPage.bind('<Lock-KeyPress>', capsoff)
LoginPage.bind('<Lock-KeyRelease>', capson)
```

This all seemed to work fine but it also left place for a few issues to arise. If the user clicked off the window and then pressed caps lock, it wouldn't register a change, so when the window was re-entered the image could potentially get stuck. As well as, there being no image to be 'place_forget()'-ed if the caps lock key was engaged when the user started the program and unclicked caps lock.

(Also, I know that it is somewhat unnecessary to use os.path.dirname and such to find an exact directory but I was having issues with working directories and moving between computers that this was the solution to resolve that.)

To try to overcome the other issues I decided I would try to check whether the caps lock was engaged or not after the button had been pressed using the 'win32api' module and then making changes accordingly. The code which I used for that was as follows:

```
def capsclick(event=None):
    caps_state=win32api.GetKeyState(0x14)
    if caps_state>0:
        print("oncap")
        capslock_image.place(x=375, y=251)
    else:
        print("offcap")
        capslock_image.place_forget()

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_name = os.path.join(dir_path, "images\\capslock.png")
img=Image.open(file_name)
img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
capslock_image=tkinter.Label(LoginPage, image=img)
capslock_image.image=img

LoginPage.bind('<Lock-KeyPress>', capsclick)
LoginPage.bind('<Lock-KeyRelease>', capsclick)
```

I decided to move the defining of the image outside of the subroutine as I wanted to handle the image in other sections of the code as well, but this code didn't seem to allow anything to happen at all. If I move the defining of the image back into the sub routine it allows the image to appear correctly again but then it won't disappear when asked to. I tried globalling the variable in case that was an issue, but that didn't seem to make an impact, and I'm really not sure why this isn't working. Also, the "oncap" and "offcap" prints do output correctly upon the selecting and de-selecting of capslock so the code is handling the flow correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The second code example works fine. I can see the image when the capslock is toggled on and the image disappears when capslock is toggled off.

Comment: @acw1668 truly strange then because it is refusing to do so for me. Can I ask if I'm able to see the code which you ran to try and see if there are any errors in mine compared? Thanks :)

Comment: I just add the missing parts like import statements, create the window and `LoginPage` (a frame). See the code [here](https://pastebin.com/F4hxqC5A).

Comment: @acw1668 yep that works for me to...must be an issue on my end, thanks for your help!

Comment: So it is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a new capslock_image label every time the capsclick function is called. I think that might be causing issues when trying to remove the label with place_forget().

Feel free to fork this, if it is useful: https://app.einblick.ai?w=63f4dff5f478ad38ccab1fe8

Comment: Unfortunately, this is essentially what I have now with no luck. Weirdly, the code which does re produce the label every time is the one which somewhat works.